# Windows 2008 64bit driver for Intel PRO/1000 PM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, intel, drivers, nic

I'm trying to upgrade the network adapter's driver on my windows 2008 dedicated server to the latest version. I checked in the device manager and I see two network adapters, Intel PRO/1000 PL and Intel PRO/1000 PM, but when I checked the network connection I found that 'Intel PRO/1000 PM' is the one being used and now I'm trying to upgrade the driver for that one (The version of the currently installed driver is 9.12.36.0).

I checked Intel's website but there seems to be no driver available for Windows 2008 (the latest they have is for Windows 2003).

Do Windows 2003 drivers work with Windows 2008? If not, am I missing anything or is there anything else I should do?

Many Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to update it?

Comment: @Zoredache, I'm just trying to make sure the latest version is installed because sometimes this makes a noticeable difference in performance: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/server-speed-tests/

Answer (score 0):

They usually do. In a lot of cases the XP-on drivers will work with the later versions too.